# how to run html dynamic pages on android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello guys I am facing one issue while running interlinked html pages on android amulator.
Its just showing index page but links are not working.

```
package neeru.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         WebView webview = new WebView(this);
         setContentView(webview);
         try {
             InputStream fin = getAssets().open("index.html");
             byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
             fin.read(buffer);
             fin.close();
             webview.loadData(new String(buffer), "text/html", "UTF-8");
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
private final static String URL = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
...
mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

then it should work.